Is it possible to add custom message / description for workflow jobs having strategy matrix?
Below is my GitHub Actions workflow.
I wish to display custom message to the approver in GitHub Actions workflow when the run prompts for approval for the environments.
I tried using the description attribute for Approvals jobs as well as for the environment but seems it is not supported.
name: Approval workflow for different environments
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:

  Approvals:
    name: ${{ matrix.envName }}
    #description: "Need different description for each matrix run"
    runs-on: Windows-latest
    strategy:
      matrix:
        envName:
          - APP_APPROVAL
          - DB_APPROVAL
    environment:
      name: ${{ matrix.envName }}
      #description: "Need different description for each matrix run"
    steps:
      - name: Extract Environment from SERVER_ENVIRONMENT
        id: getenv
        run: |
          Write-Host "Run Success"

Is it possible to display a custom message to the approvers before they approve and trigger the matrix jobs?

This description could be a value configured in the matrix strategy, just like your envName. Or you could have only one input as JSON with an envName associated to a description, that you could manipulate during the matrix execution.

I've got an example here using an array as JSON in a matrix input, with a name and a type field. Each matrix job will have access to an object of the JSON array and manipulate its fields. You could do the same with the envName and description fields in your case.
